# windows 7 - Too many files on external drive to take ownership

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I recently moved from windows 10 to windows 7, and I'm trying to access my files on the old partition, but running into this file permissions game again.

I have tried taking ownership of my user folder but there are simply too many files - think automatically generated junk files, temporary files, and cache files with long hexadecimal names. This could take hours as far as I can tell, and is probably not great for my harddrive. I frankly find it ridiculous that it has to change permissions on every file individually instead of just setting a global rule that all files under the folder are hereafter owned by me after so and so timestamp.

I've tried googling for other ways to do this, but I can't find any mention of the fact that it sits there changing every. single. file. or any way around this. It doesn't make a difference whether I do it from the gui, whether I use the `takeown` command, or whether I use the `cacls` command. It's all the same.

I'm the only user of this computer, and I do not want or need file permissions. This is not a unix mainframe with 100 users on it. It's a personal computer, so I'm looking for any way to bypass or disable this horribly broken system entirely, or whatever is needed. But preferably not something that takes 10 hours and (possibly?) wears on my hard drive.

Comment: The only way to access those files is to change the ownership of those files.

Comment: Connect to a linux PC, then you can access them without permissions nonsense.